# how to add java jaxb marshaller meta-data to root element only?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

i have the following code

```
@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
private static class MyAttribute<T> {
    private String name;

    @XmlElement(name = "value")
    private T value;
 }
 @XmlRootElement(name = "duke-eport")


@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class DukeDBInfo {


    @XmlElement(name = "sys-attribute")
    private List<MyAttribute<?>> sysAttribute;
}
```

when using jaxb marshaller with it i get the following output:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<duke-eport>
    <sys-attribute>
        <name>username</name>
        <value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">udsds</value>
    </sys-attribute>
    <sys-attribute>
        <name>ip</name>


  <value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">127.0.0.1</value>
</sys-attribute>
<sys-attribute>
    <name>server-date</name>
    <value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:dateTime">2015-05-19T16:23:09.595+03:00</value>
</sys-attribute>
```

how can i remove the xmlns:xsi and the xml:xs from each and add it only once to the root node ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.w3._2001.xmlschema.Adapter1;

@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "myAttribute", propOrder = {
"username",
"server-date"
})
private static class MyAttribute<T> {
protected String username;
@XmlElement(type = String.class)
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(Adapter1 .class)
@XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
protected Calendar server-date;

@XmlElement(username = "value")
private T value;
}
@XmlRootElement(username = "duke-eport")

@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class DukeDBInfo {


@XmlElement(username = "sys-attribute")
private List<MyAttribute<?>> sysAttribute;
}
```

Comment: i think you missed the question, i'm using java to produce the xml file

Comment: can you give me an example ?

Comment: sur see  the new response

Comment: i see your solution , but you are breaking the list so each MyAttribute have multiple fields, i don't want that because the List<MyAttribute<?>> sysAttribute will have elements each with different fields, they don't all have username and server date..

Comment: sorry, i had an error in my code , i have list of MyAttribute<T> , each My attibute<T> will have value and name only, and i don't want on each value to have xmlns..

Comment: Look exemples in this link : http://www.codesuggestions.com/java/jaxb-marshalling-unmarshalling-using-generics/ 
 also documentation here : https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/jaxb20-fcs/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAnyElement.html